# Excel ODBC connection doesn't update all data

Tags: excel, odbc, excel-2010, vba

I have an Excel Workbook that has an SQL ODBC connection to a database. The data is supposed to update in an Excel Tabel. This works fine as long as I don't touch the results.

However, while working with this table, I need to change some of the data in the columns after updating with a macro. I do NOT change the column names OR the number of columns OR the position of said columns.

However, **once the data in the table is changed, the ODBC connection no longer updates the data in the modified columns**! If I change the data in these columns, the update leaves those fields untouched. If I write nonsense in the columns, it just remains. If I leave the fiels blank, they remain blank.

It seems that the ODBC update ignores any column in which I touch the data!!!

**Does anyone have an idea why this happens?**

I investigated various possibilities, all of which turned out to be false

1. The SQL code always updates ALL of the data. It is supposed to delete the current data and FULLY load ALL new data (i.e. not just the newest records).
2. I read on MSDN Library that the update for some ODBC connections first checks the first 8 fields in the column to determine the data type. I have tried leaving the first 8 rows untouched so as not to influence the loaded data. Didn't work.
3. I have made sure that I did not accidently modify the ODBC connection or the SQL code. All remains the same.

Comment: `The data is supposed to update in an Excel Table.` Quick question: What kind of table is it? How are you updating the table with the connection.

Comment: It's considered a `ListObject` in VBA code.